# uploading ssl certificate to heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I've set everything up to secure my domain with ssl, I've received a certificate from my provider and I added the endpoint addon to heroku, however I'm having difficulties with uploading the certificates to heroku..

I have the following files:

CompleteCABundle.crt
www.domainname.crt

and some generated server.key and server.pass.key files.
I've tried to upload these to heroku with the certs:add command but so far it does not seem to be working.

What steps should be taken and which files exactly should be uploaded to heroku?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Heroku before but I imagine a problem could be that you haven't combined the CA Bundle and your domain's certificate together into a single file before trying to upload them.

According to the Heroku docs here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint there are only two arguments to the `certs:add` command.

You can combine the two .crt files with the following:

```
cat www.domainname.crt CompleteCABundle.crt > total-crt-chain.crt
```

Then try `certs:add` again (with this new bundle and your private key) and maybe see if this works.